# Are these independent: the sample, randomized rule, and random variable having the prior distribution on the parameter space?

Tags: bayesian, mathematical-statistics, decision-theory, games, random-allocation

In section 1.3 of [Bickel and Doksum's Mathematical Statistics 2006](http://amzn.to/2xppCvS), 
the risk function of a nonrandomized rule $d$ is the expectation of loss of the rule wrt the random sample.
$$
R(\theta, d) := E_{X\sim P_\theta} l(\theta, d(X))
$$

1. the risk function of a randomized rule  $\delta$ (distributed
   according to $\lambda$) is further taking expectation wrt the
   randomized rule. $$ R(\theta, \delta) := E_{\delta \sim \lambda}
   E_{X\sim P_\theta} l(\theta, d(X)) $$

   **Q:** Are the randomized rule $\delta$ and the sample supposed to be
   independent? I would like to know if we can exchange the order of
   the two expectations as:  $$ R(\theta, \delta) = E_{X\sim P_\theta}
   E_{\delta \sim \lambda}  l(\theta, \delta(X)) $$
2. In section 3.3, they studied the relation between minimax rule and
   Bayes rule in terms of some two-player 0-1 game, where they
   introduced the nature and a statistician  as the two players. The
   nature chooses a prior distribution $\pi$ over the parameter space $\Theta$,
   and the statistician chooses a randomized rule. The payoff one
   player pays to the other is

   $$ r(\pi, \delta) := E_{\theta \sim \pi} R(\theta, \delta) = E_{\theta \sim \pi} E_{\delta \sim \lambda} E_{X\sim
   P_\theta} l(\theta, \delta(X)) $$

   **Q:** Are $\theta$, the randomized rule $\delta$ and the sample supposed to be
   independent? I would like to know if we can exchange the order of
   the three expectations as:

   $$
   r(\pi, \delta) = E_{\delta \sim \lambda} E_{\theta \sim \pi} E_{X\sim P_\theta} l(\theta, \delta(X)) 
   $$
3. The reason of my question in 2 is:

   They said that given $\delta$, $\arg\max_\pi r(\pi, \delta)$, when
   exists, can be chosen to the point mass probability measure on
   $\arg\max_\theta R(\theta, \delta)$. It means that, given a randomized rule $\delta$, the least favorite prior distribution $\pi_\delta$ on $\Theta$, can chosen to be a single $\theta_\delta$, i.e. we can remove the randomization of $\theta$

   **Q:** I would like to know if it is also similarly true that given $\pi$,
   the Bayes randomized rule $\arg\min_\delta r(\pi, \delta)$, when exists, can be chosen to have
   the point mass probability measure on $\arg\min_d E_{\theta \sim \pi}
   E_{X\sim P_\theta} l(\theta, d(X)) $?

   If yes, it implies **a Bayes randomized rule is always a Bayes nonrandomized rule**. [But I am not sure if this conclusion is correct.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/126098/is-a-bayes-randomized-rule-always-a-bayes-nonrandomized-rule)

   I think that this can be true, if
   we can exchange the order of $ E_{\delta \sim \lambda}$ and $ E_{\theta
   \sim \pi}$ in $r(\pi, \delta) $ as in part 2, which is why I ask if $\theta$ and $\delta$ are independent in part 2.

Thanks.

The relevant pages are [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13029929/BD/1.pdf) for section 1.3 and [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13029929/BD/2.pdf) for section 3.3.

Comment: Thanks. @Glen_b. I have been trying to update my post for the past half an hour, but couldn't perhaps due to the site problem.

Comment: Indeed, I started experiencing problems a few minutes after I typed that comment. Whenever you can.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Are the randomized rule δ and the sample supposed to be independent?

There is no reason to restrict randomised rules in this manner. For instance, randomisation may only occur for some values of the observation/sample.

> 2. Are θ, the randomized rule δ and the sample supposed to be independent?

In a joint Bayesian model, sample and parameter are dependent since the sampling distribution is the conditional distribution. While the randomised rule cannot depend on the unknown $\theta$ in a functional manner, since it can [functionally] depend on the sample, it possibly does [probabilistically] depend on the unknown $\theta$.

> 3. a Bayes randomized rule is always a Bayes nonrandomized rule

This is incorrect: A randomised Bayes rule may differ from a non-randomised one and achieve better performances from a risk perspective. For instance, in finite parameter spaces with strictly convex losses, a minimax rule is always a randomised Bayes rule but not necessarily a non-randomised Bayes rule

Comment: On your answer to #3, could you point me in the direction to a proof of this? Thanks.

Comment: This situation is covered in my book.